# Initializing client javascript variables from nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, client

I am trying to send some extra data to a client using nodejs at the same time the server is sending html and/or javascript. I'm pretty new to web development and am probably overlooking some core concept.

Here's essentially what I would like to do.

```
require('http');

var someVar = 'Some data';

http.createServer(function(req, res){
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.write(someWebPage);

    res.sendThisDataToClient(someVar);

    res.end();
}).listen(4000);
```

And the client

```
var someVar = getDataSentWithThisPage();
// Do stuff
```

I did find a way to solve the specific problem I had in a different way although I would still like to know how to do this / if it is possible / if it is the javascript way.

Comment: Are you looking to use the data in your html before it's sent to the client (solved with templates) or once the page is loaded the data is set as a javascript variable on the client (multiple solutions).

Comment: I think the comments below already solved the problem but I needed to set some javascript variable from the server either before it is sent or as soon as the client script runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a templating engine and send your data like so:

```
res.render('index.html', { myVar : someVar }):
```

and in your index.html you'd have some expression evaluating `myVar`, for example `<% myVar %>` in ejs, or something like `span=myVar` in jade.

Comment: You aren't forced to use a template engine though. You could also just output a html page with something like this in it:
`<script> var someVar = "datablabla"; </script>`

Comment: @Hless you're absolutely right, I changed my post to "could" rather than "need to".

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot you can do that with javascript. I'm still too use to compiled languages. Thanks!